# Python Pandas - .isnull() does not work with full dataframe index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, isnull, matrix-indexing

I do not understand why i cannot use the method .isnull() for a precise element in my dataframe.

```
raw_limits['CIRL1_I[X]']
```

returns

```
0         1
1        -1
2      0,75
3     -0,75
4       NaN
5       NaN
6    -518,9
```

Then:

```
raw_limits['CIRL1_I[X]'].isnull()
```

returns

```
0    False
1    False
2    False
3    False
4     True
5     True
6    False
```

And then finally:

```
raw_limits['CIRL1_I[X]'][4].isnull()
```

brings that error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-88-e89d95cf8aa9> in <module>
      2 measure_points = list(raw_limits.columns)
      3 measure_points.remove(measure_points[0]) # Remove first entry with is "JSN"
----> 4 raw_limits['CIRL1_I[X]'][4].isnull()

AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'isnull'
```

Can somebody explain me that?
Thank you

Comment: Reason is `raw_limits['CIRL1_I[X]'][4]` return scalar, so cannot be use `Series.isnull()` method

Comment: Okay super, thanks. Which operator I can use then to return false or true?

Comment: Use `pd.isnull()` like in dupe